# How do i enclose the Single Quotes within double quotes for php variables to be interpreted

Tags: php

```
$URN  = 1
$col2 = ABC
$qty  = 10
```

the above 3 values needs to be put in span tag such as `<span id ='$URN:$col2'>$qty</span>`:

```
$row['col1']  =  "<span id = '".$urn."'>".$qty."</span>";
```

but I am getting an error.

Comment: what error? how do you assign $qty ?

Comment: post error code as the text you pasted is not erroneous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a few choices.

a. String concatenation with single quotes

```
$row['col1'] = '<span id="' . $urn . '">' . $qty . '</span>
```

b. Double quotes and escapes:

```
$row['col1'] = "<span id=\"{$urn}\">{$qty}</span>";
```

c. HEREDOC

```
$row['col1'] = <<<EOL
<span id="{$urn}">{$qty}</span>
EOL;
```

Comment: @someone this did not answer your question

Answer (score 3):

Using single quotes:

```
 $row['col1']  =  "<span id = '".$URN.":".$col2."'>".$qty."</span>";
```

Using double quotes:

```
   $row['col1']  =  "<span id = \"".$URN.":".$col2."\">".$qty."</span>";
```

Answer (score 2):

Variable names are case sensitive in PHP.
If you're getting "Undefined variable" error - well, this is it.

```
$row['col1']  =  "<span id = '$URN:$col2'>$qty</span>";
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't see any syntax errors, but the following would be a lot more readable:

```
$row['col1']  =  "<span id='$urn'>$qty</span>";
```

It might help if you were more specific about the mysterious error you are getting.

Answer (score 1):

To get exacly what you asked you need:

```
$row['col1']  =  "<span id = '".$urn.":".$col2."'>".$qty."</span>";
```

Answer (score 1):

I avoid needing to think about this problem by using the sprintf function when I want to generate HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Please escape your output (otherwise you're just opening the door for possible XSS attacks:

(Assuming UTF-8 Character set):

```
$row['col1']  =  '<span id="'.
                    htmlspecialchars($urn, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8').
                 '">'.
                    htmlspecialchars($qty, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8').
                 '</span>';
```